# Textarea placeholder weird gap (reactjs)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, textarea

I use a simple `textarea` element and add a `placeholder` and for some reason the placeholder have a weird gap from the side. The code is in React.js:

**PLEASE NOTICE: my HTML DOM structure's direction is `RTL`!**

```
<textarea
    className='inputArea'
    {...passProps}
/>
```

With the following CSS (SASS) styling:

```
.inputArea
    display: block
    width: 100%
    padding: 1rem
    overflow-y: scroll
    height: 160px
```

And this is how it look like: (with gap)

[image]

You can see the space between the carret and the placeholder text. But When I set `dir='ltr'` the gap disappears:

[image]

Also need to know, is that when I set `overflow-y: hidden` the gap disappears..

What seems to be the problem ?

Comment: Inspect the DOM and look at *all* the computed style values to see what may be adding that padding/margin/space for any of those elements.

Comment: it's happens because of the scroll wich takes `6px` of the width but I don't understand why .. ?

Comment: If I set `overflow-y` to `auto`, how would it scroll ?

Comment: Have you inspected all the elements in the text area to see what CSS rules are applied? Does the `rtl` direction also flip the justification of the input's text or is the text still left justified? I still think `overflow-y: auto;` will help as the scrollbar will only display if the content overflows.

Comment: You are right ! @DrewReese

Comment: Cool, great! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Textarea should be write like this

```
<textarea className='inputArea' {...passProps} />
```

And you need to remove the space between  tag start and end

Comment: Your suggestion is completely opinionated and absolutely 100% not the only way to write syntactically correct JSX. Some style formatters can be configured to allow only one prop per line, to allow easy single-line updates in the future (i.e. git blame).